# Effect on sleep() on static variables in c

Tags: c, multithreading, static, sleep

Can anyone please help me to understand below question?

Why does sleep() cause static variable not to keep its value in between invocations?

> Note: Below part of the codes are invoked by multiple threads
>   performing same thing.

Here is the part of the code:

```
int get_value_agent(DC_ITEM *item, AGENT_RESULT *result)
{
    const char  *__function_name = "get_value_agent";
    char *buf, buffer[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int     ret = SUCCEED;
    ssize_t     received_len;
    static char *test;
    int i,j;

    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    if (SUCCEED == (ret = tcpConnect(CONFIG_SOURCE_IP, item->interface.addr)))
    {
        zbx_snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s\n", item->key);

        if ((test = sendViaSFTP(buffer, CONFIG_SOURCE_IP, item->interface.addr)) != "FAIL")
        {
            buf = recvViaSFTP(test);
            while(!buf)
            {
                sleep(2);
                buf = recvViaSFTP(test);
                received_len = 1;
            }
        }
    }
//
}
```

Here "test" is a static variable.
The function "recvViaSFTP(test)" is called as many times till it returns some non-null value from the client.

After Execution of sleep(), the function recvViaSFTP(test) is called again. But I noticed that this time, the value stored in test became NULL.

I suspect that the variable "test" gets modified by other thread (while sleeping) after CPU is allocated for the other thread. But the confusion is that the variable "buffer" doesn't get modified even after sleeping.

Is there a way to avoid the change in the variable "test"? If it can be achieved by mutex, then can I use mutex after the point of creation of thread?

I tried the alternative way. I removed the sleep() function and found that the value stored in test was unchanged.

Sorry for my little explanation because I thought that this could be a famous question.

Please answer the so explained behavior.

Comment: Do you have any code that goes with your dilemma?

Comment: You're going to have to provide an example program where this visibly happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved the solution of this undefined behavior. This was not actually "only" due to the race-condition. I went through several posts on stackoverflow.com yesterday and got to learn that in c (particularly), if one returns the local variable like "character array" or "pointer to character" from a function to the other, then there are probable chances for this value to be lost.

I had also tried to return the local variable "test" in the line :

```
if ((test = sendViaSFTP(buffer, CONFIG_SOURCE_IP, item->interface.addr)) != "FAIL")
```

which is always lost after sleep().

Thus, I changed the code in this way from the calling function:

```
void some_Function(){
    ............................
    ............................
    do{
       sendViaSFTP(buffer, item->interface.dns_orig, &test);
       .........................
       .........................
       sleep(2);
       buf = recvViaSFTP(test);
       .........................    
       .........................
       .........................
    }while(!buf);
    if(test){
       free(test);
       test = NULL;
    }
}
```

---

```
void sendViaSFTP(const char *data, const char *pwd, char **ret)
{
          ...................
          ...................
          ...................

          finalReturn = malloc((strlen(sftppath) + 1)*sizeof(char));
          strncpy(finalReturn, sftppath, strlen(sftppath) + 1);
          *ret = finalReturn;
}
```

I mean, I passed test by reference and had its memory written with the required value. And, as a result the value in "test" was never lost.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do that directly. All `sleep()` does is suspend the thread that has encountered the `sleep()` function. Another thread could modify the static variable. (But another thread could could do that anyway; irrespective of whether or not other threads are sleeping).

Comment: I have provided the code above. Please help mt to get answer in that context.

Comment: Please answer on the basis of above codes. Yes, you are right as variables may be changed by other threads. But, as shown in the above codes, the variable "buffer" is also used by other threads. But still, this variable is never changed and the variable "test" which is of "char *" type is changed to -> "" after waking up from sleep. Why is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The C11 memory model states that data races are undefined behavior. Any time you access the same variable with two different threads and at least one of them is writing the behavior is undefined. In your case there is a data race on `test` which is a good reason for the weird behavior. Use mutexes to protect every concurrent access to shared variables.

Also you are using `__function_name` which is a reserved identifier because it starts with two underscores.

Comment: Thanks @nwp for replying. This undefined behavior makes sense. Ok, I will try to lock the variable using mutex. 
About the latter part, "__function_name" is the reserved identifier of the tool "zabbix" I am using and it used just to print the function name where the control is in while debugging. I hope that doesn't affects this so called "unidentified behavior". Isn't it?

Comment: @rohit Identifiers starting with `__` are reserved for the implementation. Strictly speaking using them is undefined behavior. An implementation could use `__function_name` for the compiler and do crazy things with your code, but that is unlikely. You should still rename it, there is no reason to risk it. Also you should look up the details of undefined behavior, it is unintuitive, cannot be learned with learning by doing and can break your code in the weirdest ways.